# Ros noetic on debian bullseye

Tags: debian, dual-boot

I'm trying to install ros noetic from source on my debian bullseye. However i have multiple issues with ogre, dependencies and more. I'm thinking to downgrade to buster do you know how i can do that? I have a dual boot and I don't want to alterate my windows partition.

Comment: Don't think downgrading to a debian version that's end-of-live for nearly a year will solve any problems, but produce a lot additional ones.

Comment: You should probably ask for help with compilation instead! There's a few approaches where you can use your still-supported system and still build software that depends on things in a version that isn't available. But really, chances are that things are very solvable.

Comment: In essence, ROS has its own package management system which it reads to know which packages to install on your debian. And of course, that's kind of a terrible idea (compared to just using debian's method of installing dependencies: writing a debian package that does nothing but depend on the right software, and upstreaming it to debian, so that you could then just `apt install ros-noetic` or similar…). All you would need to do is fix a few ROS package files (it's not that many; I've just tricked ROS noetic into starting ot build (it will not work) on current debian stable). But assuming you

Comment: … "just" want to quickly build on a specific set of dependencies, there's solutions for that! Sadly, describing these really don't fit here, because you're not asking about that.